# PHP retain selectbox value after postbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to dynamically pull the second dropdown list value from the first dropdown list, I am currently having an issue that my first dropdown list selected value is being reset to the first upon every postback.

In my case `[php useadvancedfilter] is <?php and [php useadvancedfilter] is ?>`

```
        $dateofcoupon = $_POST["dateofcoupon"];
        <form id="form1" name="form1" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
        <select name="dateofcoupon" onchange="run()" id="dateofcoupon">
        [php useadvancedfilter]
        while($fetch_couponalldetais = mysql_fetch_array($getcouponalldetais )){
        $checkcoupon = $fetch_couponalldetais['coupon-date']
        [/php useadvancedfilter]
        <option [php useadvancedfilter] if(isset($dateofcoupon) && $dateofcoupon==$fetch_couponalldetais['coupon-date']) echo "selected"; [/php useadvancedfilter] value="[php useadvancedfilter] echo $fetch_couponalldetais['coupon-date']; [/php useadvancedfilter]">[php useadvancedfilter] echo $fetch_couponalldetais['coupon-date']; [/php useadvancedfilter]</option>
        [php useadvancedfilter]
        }
        [/php useadvancedfilter]
        </select>
        </form>
```

Using a JavaScript to submit form

```
<script>
function run(){
   document.getElementById("form1").submit();
}
document.getElementById("dateofcoupon").value = "<?php echo $_POST['dateofcoupon'];?>";
</script>
```

Comment: Which framework are you using, Joomla?

Comment: @Fred-ii- WordPress, but fully flexible to use PHP, jQuery, JavaScript without any limitations.

Comment: Ok, wasn't sure whether the relevant tag should be included.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, within pages to use PHP, I should use that tag instead of <?php

Comment: I meant the `wordpress` tag for your question, where you presently used `javascript,php...` etc.

Comment: @Fred-ii- True, but for me question seems general and doesn't have any relationship with framework so I didn't mention it.

Comment: I understand. That's why I wasn't sure whether the tag was needed or not. Sometimes it helps and to target Wordpress savvy people.

Answer (score 1):

You are just using javascript to access the native submit method, which submits the form and reloads the page. in order to achieve a form submission without reloading the page(which is what causes the form to reset), you will need to look into the ajax api methods.

so function `run()` could be replaced by a simple jQuery function. something like this:

```
$(function(){ //document.ready() shortcut
    $('#form1').submit( function(){ //the submit event
        var QueryString = $(this).serialize(); //get the form values
        $.post('your-url.php',QueryString, function(data){ //post the form with the querystring, then setup the callback
            alert(data);//your data callback
        });
        return false;//prevent native browser form submission
    });
});
```

**for more information on ajax methods with jquery, see :**

**[jquery post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)**

**[jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**

**[jquery get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)**

**[jquery getjson](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)**